# Return Specific Constraint that is Infeasible in Drake

Tags: drake

I am currently running a MIQP optimization problem in Drake using Gurobi.
I keep on getting an infeasible solution to my optimization problem and I wanted to know if Drake can return any more useful information such as which specific constraint is causing the infeasibility.

I already have returned the type of error (ex:  GRB_INFEASIBLE, GRB_UNBOUNDED, GRB_INF_OR_UNBD) from the gurobi.cc file.

Otherwise if such helpful function does not exist, could you offer some tips on debugging a large optimization problem? (Other than creating small test cases)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to debug the mixed-integer optimization problem. For gurobi, you could try the function [computeIIS()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/c_computeiis.html). Do you use the pydrake or the C++ version? If you have the C++ source code, then the easiest way is to to add the following code before this line https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/3f1482d4808d238ee63095ba05c18434b47d1fbf/solvers/gurobi_solver.cc#L1058

```
GRBcompueIIS(model);
GRBwrite(model, `infeasible.ilp`)
```

Gurobi will write the infeasible constraint to a text file name `infeasible.ilp`. If you have set the name of the variables, by calling `NewContinuousVariable(size, var_name)`, then the infeasible report `infeasible.ilp` will use the variable name `var_name`.

Unfortunately we cannot associate the infeasible constraint in Gurobi `computeIIS` function to the constraint you added through Drake, namely it doesn't report which Drake constraint causes the infeasibility yet.

BTW, we have a [tutorial](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/debug_mathematical_program.ipynb) on debugging MathematicalProgram in Drake. It is mostly for nonlinear optimization with gradient based solvers.

Comment: BTW, I filed a github issue https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/14944, I will add the first two features in that issue soon.

Comment: I tried to add the 2 lines of code. Both of the status return is 0. However, there is no file being created. Would you know why it does not create the infeasible.ilp file?
Minor fixes to your lines: 
int iis_status = GRBcomputeIIS(model);
int ilp_status = GRBwrite(model, "infeasible.ilp");

Comment: When you call `GRBcomputeIIS`, is the program infeasible? You could turn on the verbose report of Gurobi, by doing
```
prog.SetSolverOption(GurobiSolver::id(), "OutputFlag", True);
```
it will print out some progress on the screen. You could check the feasibility from that progress report.

Comment: Yes, the "Model is infeasible" is what it output. 
Also just to make sure, should it output that file in the "solvers" folder? (same place as where gurobi_solver.cc is)

Comment: It would output to where you run your binary target, not necessarily the solvers folder.